# Unity - Player Teleports on Jump Pad

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've joined a game jam, and I'm making a 2D platformer in Unity for it. For this I've created a Jump Pad. Whenever the player character stands on it they'll jump. The problem is that the jump doesn't look like a jump, it looks more like a teleportation upwards. Any fixes? Code below!

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.tag == "Spike") {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    } else if (other.tag == "Jump Pad") {
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpSpeed));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W915h.jpg

Comment: Increase the jumpSpeed from the Editor.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `OnTriggerEnter2D` code you have posted.  I used this method in a previous project I worked on.  Are you sure there is nothing in your code that is directly setting the `transform.position`?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. Also, @Programmer that wouldn't help at all. The player does jump, it just looks very weird. I'll upload a GIF in a second.

Comment: It might also help if you post a screenshot of your rigidbody component from the inspector so we can see how it's configured.

Comment: See edited post :D

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
  if(other.gameObject.tag == "player")
    {
       //you can change 20 to whatever number you want
       other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 20), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Note : be sure to tag the player "player"
Note 2 : be sure is trigger is off

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add upward force like below
`rb.AddForce(transform.up*jumpSpeed);`
Note: Set a 'realistic' jumpSpeed.

Comment: The looks aren't affected in anyway. I've already tried that. :(

Comment: What is your jumpSpeed variable?

Answer (score -1):

DUDE. lol so i just tried this and what do u know it was giving me trouble, but what i did was take that trigger script off the player and have the jumppad detect the trigger.

```
 if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpSpeed));

        }
```

tag ur player `player` and put this on the jump pad and set to istrigger

Comment: It does the same exact thing... :P

Comment: Try toning down the jumpSpeed

Comment: That doens't change a thing. It's just like all other answers then :P

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the Jump Speed I think.

Comment: i think its the jump speed or you have omething else acting on it. your speed is set to 5000, mine lookes good between 500 and 1000, at 5000 it skips around

Comment: any luck figuring this out @Xaaf Code? this baffles me.

Comment: No. Haven't figured this one out. Project is dead now anyways :(